# Passing Runnable to Thread object which was initially created with Zero argument?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have written this program:

```
public class ThreadWithNoRunnable {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("This is work getting progressed");
            }
        }
        MyRunnable r = new MyRunnable();
        Thread t = new Thread();
        t.start();
    }
}
```

I created a `Thread object` with zero argument constructor. How do I pass my `Runnable object` to this `thread t` object, so that it executes `run() of MyRunnable`. If this isn't possible,then why we have a zero argument Thread consutuctor?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Thread class empty constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9244147/thread-class-empty-constructor)

Comment: Or this one [Why would anyone ever use the Java Thread no argument constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7572527/why-would-anyone-ever-use-the-java-thread-no-argument-constructor)

Comment: And the canonical [“implements Runnable” vs “extends Thread” in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541487/implements-runnable-vs-extends-thread-in-java). There's no way to set the `Thread` instance's work (`run` or `Runnable`) after it's be instantiated.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help. I was trying to understand why there is default constructor with which a Thread object can be created and then later we can't be able to pass any custom Runnable Object. My intentions isn't to subclass Thread and override run(), rather was seeing if there is something I don't understand. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score -3):

I guess what you might want is a subclass of `Thread`:

```
public class ThreadWithNoRunnable extends Thread {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        start(); //`this` is `Thread`, so it has `start`
    }

    //`run` will be the entry point on the background thread
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("This is work getting progressed");
    }
}
```

Pretty much same results, but less typing.